# Howto localize a symfony2 custom login handler?

Tags: symfony, authentication, localization

seems I really get into trouble localizing our symfony2 application. At least I can't find any way to make it work. Here's my problem:

We have a symfony2 app with a login handler and currently without any localization. I learned, that I have to prepend every path in the *routing.yml* with a {_locale}. Well, every path except /login and /login_check. My root entry now reads like this:

```
root:
   pattern: /
   defaults:
       _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
       path: /%locale%
       permanent: true
```

Depending on the settings in my browser I get to /en, /fr, /pl and so on. Works nice. Now I have a login handler defined in the *session.yml* like this:

```
secured_area:
    pattern: ^/(fileupload|mydata|mysettings|myprofile|login_check|home|my_items)
    form_login:
        check_path: /login_check
        login_path: /login
        success_handler: login_success_handler
```

The login_success_handler is a service, derived from AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface. I need it for the methods onSecurityInteractiveLogin and onAuthenticationSuccess. The latter one I need to check, if the user's account is fully activated or not. Depending on this fact I must redirect him either to the default home page or to an info page.

As symfony gets the locale settings from the url, here we get into trouble because "/login_check" has no locale. It's not possible to put {_locale} into the session.yml and - according to the documentation - it's should not be neccessary. But here I have to generate and return a RedirectResponse with the target url. This url is crafted by the router, which is injected into the service.

```
return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('_welcome_user'));
```

_welcome_user is defined in the routing.yml like this:

```
_welcome_user:
    path:  /{_locale}/home
    defaults: { _controller: MasterpieceMainBundle:Start:index }
```

But in fact the generated url looks this way:

```
http://localhost/Symfony/Masterpiece/web/login_check/home
```

but it should read

```
http://localhost/Symfony/Masterpiece/web/en/home
```

This is my first trouble. My second trouble is, that the user is NOT authenticated.

If I remove every "{_locale}" from the *routing.yml* everything works fine again.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Hennes

Comment: Is your form_login indented ok? In your example above, it should be right below the pattern. Also try to give us the pattern. My guess is you should write the pattern in expression language to catch all locales.

Comment: You're right, the source is indented okay, but I made a mistake here in the editor. Sorry for that. I also added the patterns, well, some of them, it's a really long list.